# Convex optimization with the help of Multiplicative Weights Update Method

Tags: algorithms, optimization, approximation

I've already asked this question over at [MathExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449367/using-the-multiplicative-weights-update-method-on-concave-functions), but since I received no replies or comments there, I hoped it might be more adequately fitting in this category.

I have a convex (concave) objective function with constraints that are all linear, and would like to use the Multiplicative Weights Update method (see [MWU](http://theoryofcomputing.org/articles/v008a006/)) to optimize it. Has anybody done something like this before, or seen a paper on the topic? My searches so far have been rather unsuccessful, so I'd appreciate every hint/idea or even reference.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  For future reference: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, feel free to flag for migration, but don't re-post another copy.

Comment: Can you ask a more specific question about where you get stuck? There are many lecture notes, surveys, etc on the internet about the multiplicative weights algorithm.

Comment: @ D.W. Thank you, especially for the hint about migration, I didn't have that in mind. I will for next time :-)

@usul I'll try: I've found for example the paper by [Chekuri, Jayram, Vondrak] (http://chekuri.cs.illinois.edu/papers/mwu-submod.pdf) , which does optimization on concave functions the same as I saw it (reducing the (linear) constraints to only one), but I'm missing a clearer explanation on how to actually optimize the concave function under that one constraint. Maybe that's supposed to be general knowledge in that field and I as an undergrad student just don't know it :-/

Comment: An online search of "multiplicative weights for linear programming" leads me to these lecture notes and survey. But I don't know about the extension to a convex objective function. http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15859-f11/www/ http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs6820/2013fa/handouts/mw.pdf https://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~elbassio/lec/fpc-lecture2.pdf  https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~arora/pubs/MWsurvey.pdf

Comment: @usul Thank you for the input. I've been reading through these papers, but it seems they are not covering more than linear programming (which I hope to have kinda understood). Maybe my knowledge of Convex Optimization is the problem, I will try to work on that and then come back to the earlier mentioned paper by Chekuri...